# Updating Column Reference for Series of Checkboxes Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, calendar

This is likely a quite simple question, but I'm having trouble bringing everything together myself. Essentially what I have are a series of checkboxes representing days of the month from April to December 2022 in calendar form. Each checkbox references cell in a 'calculator' sheet for the TRUE/FALSE value. This I was able to set up manually so they go from from 1 to 275 in order. However, I have multiple sheets representing a series of users—each with the same arrangement of checkboxes.

Currently, each checkbox is set up thusly:

```
=Calculator!$B$2
```

The column remains the same, but the row increases for each date. Pretty straightforward.

What I want to be able to do is update the column using Excel VBA so User 1 would be in column B (already set up), User 2 would be in column C, User 3 would be in column D, etc. Unfortunately, this is where I'm struggling with my knowledge of VBA.

The main issue is as I see it, is that the way I have the checkboxes organized, they're difficult to iterate through traditionally (i.e., they don't start at cell A1 and go down to cell A275). My solution was to simply replace the B column reference with the next column using a basic VBA script. I found one that iterates through the checkboxes and tried to combine it with the Replace function:

```
Sub LinkCheck()
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    cb.LinkedCell = Replace(Formula, "B", "C")
    Next cb
End Sub
```

While this script runs, it simply deletes the contents of the checkbox, rather than updating the column value. I've had an extensive look around for a solution, but the majority of answers I found are far more involved than my rather simple situation.

Apologies if the solution is exceptionally simple, I'm still trying to learn my way around VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to rename your checkboxes in some consistent way so each one can be associated with a known row based on its name.

You can do that using code:

```vb
Dim cb, rw As Long

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    rw = Range(cb.LinkedCell).Row
    Debug.Print cb.Name, rw
    cb.Name = "CbCal_" & Format(rw, "000") 'rename according to linked row
    Debug.Print cb.Name, rw
Next cb
```

You need to do a bit more work when switching out the columns though - otherwise the current checkbox setting will update the new column, rather than the new column updating the checkboxes.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    SetCheckBoxColumn "E"
    SetCheckBoxColumn "F"
    SetCheckBoxColumn "G"
End Sub

Sub SetCheckBoxColumn(colLetter As String)
    Const WS_NAME As String = "Calculator"
    Dim cb, rw As Long, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    'probably want to specify a specific sheet and not ActiveSheet...
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        rw = CLng(Split(cb.Name, "_")(1))                 'using the naming from above...
        Set c = Worksheets(WS_NAME).Cells(rw, colLetter)  'get the linked cell
        cb.LinkedCell = ""                                'unlink the checkbox
        cb.Value = c.Value                                'set the checkbox value to the cell value
        cb.LinkedCell = WS_NAME & "!" & colLetter & rw    'relink the checkbox
    Next cb
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: after thinking about it more, this (below) would be better since it doesn't require renaming the checkboxes and is driven by the position of any existing linked cell.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    'SetCheckBoxColumn Sheet3, "E"
    'SetCheckBoxColumn Sheet3, "F"
    SetCheckBoxColumn Sheet3, "G"
End Sub

'Loop over all checkboxes on `wsCB` and adjust linked cell (if set) to
'   Column `ColLetter` on the same row
Sub SetCheckBoxColumn(wsCB As Worksheet, colLetter As String)
    Dim cb, rw As Long, c As Range, ws As Worksheet, lnk
    For Each cb In wsCB.CheckBoxes
        lnk = cb.LinkedCell
        If Len(lnk) > 0 Then
            Set c = Range(lnk)
            cb.LinkedCell = ""
            Set c = c.EntireRow.Columns(colLetter)
            cb.Value = c.Value
            cb.LinkedCell = "'" & c.Parent.Name & "'!" & c.Address
            Debug.Print lnk, cb.LinkedCell
        End If
    Next cb
End Sub
```